# Java 8: how to create a map out from two String lists

Tags: list, java-8

I have two lists:

```
List<String> ids
List<String> names
```

The task is to create one `Map<String,String>` out of these two lists, preferably using Java 8.
Unfortunatly, I did not find how to make it when we have lists with String type.

Comment: The question is not clear. Which should be the key - I guess ids? Are the ids unique. Are the lists the same size? How should they be grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the lists have the same size & ids are unique & ids are the keys of the map and names are corresponding values, you can use the following code to create a map:

```
Map<String,String> idsNames = IntStream.range(0,ids.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ids.get(i),names.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Sorry if my question was not very clear.

Comment: There's no need to create an intermediate `Map.Entry` for each `i`. Just using `IntStream.range(0,ids.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(ids::get, names::get))` should suffice. It's also worth mentioning that this approach works well if both lists are random access, i.e. `ArrayList`.